# How to pass ngModel from child to parents (child to parent to parent)?

Tags: angular, typescript, forms

I have a couple for parent components using **Template driven form**:

```
user-data.components.ts
admin-data.components.ts
customer-data.components.ts
```

The form elements in those components are child component using `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR`:

```
app-input.component.ts
```

which is being bind it in each of the parents like:

**`<app-input name="xxxx" [(ngModel)]="yyyy" ....></app-input>`**

In the other hand, I have in each of those parent components some default fields e.g. **firstName** and **lastName**

So for the default fields, I want to created an extra component: **`default-fields.component.ts`** with **`firstName`** and **`lastName`**:

**`<app-input name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="yyyy" ....></app-input>`**

**`<app-input name="lastName" [(ngModel)]="yyyy" ....></app-input>`**

to add it once in the parents.

My issue is that I can pass the `ngModel` from **`app-input.component.ts`** to **`default-fields.component.ts`** but not one level more deeper. For example to `user-data.components.ts`

In `default-fields.component.ts` I use **`viewProviders: []`** like:

```
@Component({
    selector: .....,
    templateUrl: .....,
    viewProviders: [ { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm } ]
})
```

Is my concept totally wrong? Am I just implementing it in the wrong way?

Comment: I'd recommend reactive forms for such manipulations (https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). It's much more flexible.

Comment: you can pass the model value to the child component  but then the child has to pass it down to it's child.Or best to use a service and inject it across to get the desired data.

Comment: Hi if i understand if you want to pass some value to different component parent or children i think the best way its to create a service with BehaviorSubject and asObservable

Comment: If you're trying to create sub forms have a look at https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-sub-form

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is creating a service with BehaviorSubject and pass the datas by next(). Then just you have to subscribe it